# how to return an array from a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I've been trying to get an array of ints back from a thread. I think I'm really close. The errors I'm getting are about dereferencing a void pointer and invalid use of a void expression here

assn3.c:29:29: error: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [-Werror]

```
printf(" %d", (int)answer[j]);
                         ^
```

assn3.c:29:18: error: invalid use of void expression

```
printf(" %d", (int)answer[j]);
```

I've tried changing the return type of my functions to int* but it didn't seem to like that. What am I missing here?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *getFactors(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = argc; i > 0; i--)
    {
            void *answer;
            pthread_t tid;
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            if (atoi(argv[i])<0)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%d must be > 0\n", atoi(argv[i]));
                    return -1;
            }

            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_create(&tid, &attr, getFactors, argv[i]);
            pthread_join(tid, &answer);

            printf("%d", atoi(argv[i]));
            printf(":");

            for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(answer); j++)
            {
                    printf(" %d", (int)answer[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And the thread function

```
void *getFactors(void *param)
{
    int a[10];
    int n = atoi(param);

    int i = 0;
    while (n%2 == 0)
    {
            a[i] = 2;
            n/=2;
            i++;
    }
    int f=3;
    while (f * f <= n)
    {
            if (n % f == 0)
            {
                    a[i]=f;
                    n /= f;
                    i++;
            }
            else
            {
                    f += 2;
            }
    }
    if (n<1)
    {
            a[i]=n;
            i++;
    }

    int* buffer = (int*) malloc(i);
    buffer = a;
    return (void *) buffer;

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void *answer;
...
int * answer_beeing_an_int_arr = answer;
printf(" %d", answer_beeing_an_int_arr[j]);
```

This is what you want. But you find that:

```
printf(" %d", (int)answer[j]);
```

does not work. Why you ask? It's because the cast `(int)` has lower precedence than the array subscript `[j]`, and also you don't tell the compiler that `answer` is a pointer to `int`s, only that it should first get the value, then cast to int. You want this:

```
printf(" %d", ((int*)answer)[j]);
```

You want to tell the compiler, that the answer is a pointer to int. Then you want to add to that that pointer `sizeof(int) * j` bytes and dereference it.

And remember to `free(answer)`.

Now to your code:

```
buffer = a;
```

is wrong. It assigns the pointer to another pointer. You want to copy the values behind the pointers, not pointers themselves. You need:

```
memcpy(buffer, a, sizeof(int) * i);
```

or

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
    buffer[j] = a[j];
}
```

to copy array values.

```
... = malloc(i);
```

This will allocate `i` bytes. An `int` does not have 1 byte (`CHAR_BIT` bits, probably 8). It has more. It can be 2, can be more. `sizeof(int)` will tell you how many bytes an `int` has. So it has to be:

```
int *buffer = malloc(i * sizeof(int));
```

or as I like it:

```
int *buffer = malloc(i * sizeof(*buffer));
```

Also:

```
int* buffer = (int*) malloc(i);
...
return (void *) buffer;
```

No need to cast a pointer to `void*` and from `void*`. `void*` is a generic pointer, it's a pointer to nothing. Just:

```
int* buffer = malloc(i * sizeof(*buffer));
...
return buffer;
```

Comment: Good answer you a faster than me)), you also can add about unreachable code after return in thread, and sigfault in for loop without args, because even if there is no args, argc would be 1 and we try to access to NULL argv[1], to solve it int i = argc - 1 in for loop.

Comment: Sorry I have been busy with other things. All of these solutions worked great except for one thing. I found that sizeof(buffer) always returned 8, and sizeof(*buffer) always returns 4, regardless of how many elements you've put into the pointer array. That is because when you use sizeof() on a pointer array it only returns the size of the pointer, which is 8 in my case. 

In order to properly print out the results in my main function I added a 0 at the end of my array and then changed my for condition to

((int*)answer)[j] != 0;

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here:

1. `for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(answer); j++)` // This will *NOT* tell you the #/elements in the array
2. `pthread_join()` is probably not the best way to pass back your integer buffer
3. And, of course, `printf(" %d", (int)answer[j]);` is a compile error :(

SUGGESTION:

Read through this tutorial, and restructure your code accordingly:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Or you can scan through this:

http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/multi-thread/multi-thread.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to correct as pointed earlier.

As pointed, do not use a local variable as a return address. It will not be accessible when the thread returns. It is better to use a global variable and allocate memory dynamically. You can free it in the function which has created the thread.

For accessing variables which are changed by a thread, you can either pass it to the thread function using the fourth argument in pthread_create(3) and later access it. Or access it using pthread_join as a return value.

Might need to use a mutex or other synchronization primitives if multiple threads are accessing the variable.

One simple example of returning an array using pthread_join(3) is given below.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <errno.h>

    #define ARRAY_LEN 10
    void *functionPthread(void *);

    int *retArray;

    int main()
    {
            int rc, i;
            pthread_t th;
            retArray = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) *ARRAY_LEN);

            if(rc = pthread_create(&th, NULL, &functionPthread, NULL))
            {
                    printf("Thread creation failed, return code %d, errno %d", rc, errno);
            }

            pthread_join(th, (void**)&retArray);

            for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++)
                    printf("%d ", retArray[i]);
            printf("\n");
            free(retArray);
            return 0;
    }

    void *functionPthread(void *)
    {
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++)
                    retArray[i] = i;
            return retArray;
    }
```